# unable to access ASPNETDB.mdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, aspnetdb

I added the reference to the static ROLES class below to assign the role to people that JOIN the website.  I tested the code and the application hung when I pressed the button on the JOIN ASP.Net control.  Of course, I immediately tried debug to find the problem but I could no longer access the SQL Express ASPNETDB.mdf - the error is listed below.  Thanks in advance.

```
**The code-behind in the Join.aspx file:**
    public partial class Join : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MembershipUser loggedIn = Membership.GetUser();
            if (loggedIn == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Session["userName"] = loggedIn.UserName;
                Roles.AddUserToRole(loggedIn.ToString(), "MEMBER");

            }
        }

    }
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:** Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user 'SFP\Susan'.

Web Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
                path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="ADMIN" />
            <allow roles="MEMBER" />
            <allow roles="GUEST" />
            <allow roles="RESTAURANT" />
        </authorization>
        <roleManager enabled="true" />
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
                    assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FCGuideEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FCGuide.csdl|res://*/FCGuide.ssdl|res://*/FCGuide.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\FCGuide.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The STACK TRACE

Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'SFP\Susan'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'SFP\Susan'.

Source Error:

Line 48:             restCity4.Text = featuredList4[0].CITY.CITY_NAME;
Line 49: 
Line 50:             MembershipUser loggedIn = Membership.GetUser();
Line 51:             if (loggedIn == null)
Line 52:             {

Source File: H:\FCGuide\FCGuide\default.aspx.cs    Line: 50

**Stack Trace:**

[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'SFP\Susan'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064474
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +95
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +206
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) +1169
   System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) +63
   System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser() +19
   FCGuide._default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in H:\FCGuide\FCGuide\default.aspx.cs:50
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

Comment: Have you connected by adding the database in the server explorer.

Comment: Yes, I can open the DB in Server Explorer and see the tables and their contents.

Comment: may be this resolves your error http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/b32c862a-799c-43c4-a731-c4811078c8bd/

Comment: Should there be a connection string for the ASPNETDB.mdf?

Comment: find ASPNETDB.mdf in C and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if user's **default** database is accessible and there is a user for your login in that database. You can check what's your default database from SSMS.

Comment: I have 2 SQL Express DBs ... one for my application and nother for the membership provider (ASPNETDB.mdf).  When I open SSMS, I can see the aspnetdb.mdf db and view the tables.  Not sure what you mean by 'default' database since I have two???

Comment: Go to `Security` -> `Logins` -> `Susan` -> `Properties` -> `Default database`.

Comment: When I look at the DB persmissions in SSMS, the only permission is 'Connect SQL' and the grantor is 'sa' .... whoever that is.

Comment: Is that under Visual Studo or SSMS?

Comment: I don't see a Security menu option under either

Comment: `Security` node is directly in your root node in Object Explorer, on the same level as `Databases` node, not in either database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5377/discussion-between-susan-and-magnatlu)

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt open it because I had `SQL2008`, and the database `ASPNETDB.MDF` was actually from `SQL2008-R2`. Got it opened in `R2`, then proceeded from there.